# Using javascript with python selenium to get required value

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from https://www.facebook.com/public/nitin-solanki page. I can get all values apart from these label (values for these label I am already getting)

Someone suggested me to use Javascript executer with python to get these label, which I added, but they do not print any value neither give error.

`Studied at` `Lives in` `From`

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/public/nitin-solanki")         
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mbm")))
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mbm.detailedsearch_result'):
        result = {}
        v =  s.find_element_by_css_selector('.fsm.fwn.fcg')
        x = v.find_elements_by_class_name('fbProfileBylineLabel')
        for y in x:
           #print y.text #this should give me label like lives in, studied at but does not
            #js line which does not give any result
            print x.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;");
            print driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;",x);
            #js ends
            z = y.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            for a in z:
                print a.text #I want to get label for this value along with it
```

Comment: `print y.text` works for me; `executeScript` is not a Python Selenium method, `execute_script` is

Comment: @dm295: thanks for comment, can you please help me to but anchor tag value associated with `y.text` in dictionary?

Comment: may you stop using `a`, `v`, `z` as the name of variable